How does the waiting behaviour of gnu parallel work in pipes?
I am using parallel from apt install parallel on WSL.
I'm looking to understand the mechanism that explains

How long will the wait be before 1st number shows up
What numbers will be printed every second.
Why is there a final print of all numbers at once at the end

Specific Questions

seq 10 | parallel -j 1 'sleep 1; echo {}' | parallel -j 4 'echo "prefix" {}'
seq 10 | parallel -j 4 'sleep 1; echo {}' | parallel -j 1 'echo "prefix" {}'
seq 10 | parallel -j 4 'sleep 1; echo {} | echo "prefix" {}'

Why does option 1 wait 6 seconds, start printing 1 per second until prefix 5 then dump all at once from 6 to 10?
Why does option 2 wait 1 second, then output 1-3, 4-7, 8-10 in next 3 seconds?
Why does option 3 wait 1 second, then output 1-4, 5-8, 9-10 in next 3 seconds?
General Questions
What are the differences in below designs

input | parallel command1 | parallel command2 (maps to option 1 and 2 above)
input | parallel 'command1 | command2' (maps to option 3 above)
input | parallel command1 | command2

I don't have a specific use case at the moment, but trying to understand the considerations involved when deciding among the 3 designs.

You are hitting some crappy design, that has since been improved.
Today output is delayed one job (i.e. output from job 1 is printed when job 2 finished).
$ seq 10 | parallel -j 1 'sleep 1; echo {}' | parallel-20210922 -j 4 'echo "prefix" {}' | timestamp -d
4.445 prefix 1
4.451 prefix 2
4.456 prefix 3
5.552 prefix 4
6.564 prefix 5
7.686 prefix 6
8.817 prefix 7
9.948 prefix 8
11.082 prefix 9
11.086 prefix 10

$ seq 10 | parallel -j 1 'sleep 1; echo {}' | parallel-20211022 -j 4 'echo "prefix" {}' | timestamp -d
2.199 prefix 1
3.295 prefix 2
4.409 prefix 3
5.527 prefix 4
6.541 prefix 5
7.663 prefix 6
8.793 prefix 7
9.924 prefix 8
11.066 prefix 9
11.070 prefix 10

